# Trying to create a calculator in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a calculator in Java. 
here is all my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Calculator {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{

        Calculator.Calculating();

    } 

    public static void Calculating() {

        String usersCalc;

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("Enter your calculation: ");
        usersCalc = userInput.next();

        //splits when sees plus
        String[] parts = usersCalc.split("+");

        //everything left to splitter
        String part1 = parts[0];
        //everything right to splitter
        String part2 = parts[1];
        int result;

        int answerOne = Integer.parseInt(part1);
        int answerTwo = Integer.parseInt(part2);

        switch (usersCalc){
        case '+':
            result = answerOne + answerTwo;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = part1 - part2;
            break;
        case '/':
            result = part1 / part2;
            break;
        case'*':
            result = part1 * part2;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to do it so that the user enters a string like "2+2" and then I split it on symbol and then put it through a switch statement and it calculates it for me. however the code still has errors which I can't resolve.
any ideas?

`errors`
Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted

Comment: **however the code still has errors** kindly mention them in question.

Comment: Hi Obese, As Naman mentioned please put down what errors you are getting.

Comment: updated question with errors

Comment: I have provide a answer, which include working code and analysis of your code. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Try with contains() to check if it's `+`, `-`, `*` or `/`. Then split it and calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common task for java interview: "Calculate value from string expression"

Here is the algorithm (Pseudo):

1. Check that expression is valid
2. Build a thee structure with two types of nodes - math operation and number
3. Recursively calculate the result

Comment: @BenKnoble yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

because usersCalc  is a String so use `"+"` in place of '+'

Answer (score 0):

You code have many errors:

1. In the switch case you are not using correct data for calculation. using `part1` and `part2` instead of `answerOne` and `answerTwo` `Integer` values.
2. You are passing `String` in the `switch` and using `char` for `case statements`.
3. For division, you should check the second value is not zero. Otherwise it will throw exception at runtime..

You can use `regex` for splitting the input. Then find the `operator` and pass it to the `switch-statement`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{

    Calculator.Calculating();

  }

  public static void Calculating() {

    String usersCalc;

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println("Enter your calculation: ");
    usersCalc = userInput.next();

    //splits when sees plus
    String[] parts = usersCalc.split("[+-/*]");

    char operator = usersCalc.contains("+") ? '+' : usersCalc.contains("-") ? '-' : usersCalc.contains("*") ? '*' : '/';

    //everything left to splitter
    String part1 = parts[0];
    //everything right to splitter
    String part2 = parts[1];
    int result = -1;

    int answerOne = Integer.parseInt(part1);
    int answerTwo = Integer.parseInt(part2);

    switch (operator){
      case '+':
        result = answerOne + answerTwo;
        break;
      case '-':
        result = answerOne - answerTwo;
        break;
      case '/':
        if (answerTwo == 0) {
          System.out.println("Invalid input.");
          return;
        }
        result = answerOne / answerTwo;
        break;
      case'*':
        result = answerOne * answerTwo;
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. split the string by checking all possible operators

   ```
   String[] parts = usersCalc.split("[+,-,*,/]");
   ```
2. check if userCalc contains the operator and do the same like

   ```
   if (usersCalc.contains("+"))
       result = answerOne + answerTwo;
   else if (usersCalc.contains("-"))
       result = answerOne - answerTwo;
   ......
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is propably because you try to compile with a version <1.7 (guessing from your error). 
To use String with switch you need at least 1.7.

That won't resolve all your problems as other answers mention it you use String in the switch and char for the cases.

Also even with the switch statement it wont work because in "usersCalc" is still the complete calculation (e.g. 2+2) and not just the "+"

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Calc extends MouseAdapter implements ActionListener
{
    JButton[] b=new JButton[28];
    static JTextField tf,tf2;
    JFrame jf;
    static double val1=0,val2=0,result=0;
    static int operator=0,plus=1,minus=1,mul=1,div=1,rem=1,no=0,sqrt=0,hit=0,dot=0,pp=0,mp=0,mulp=0,divp=0,remp=0; //mp,pp,remp,mulp,divp all the used for operator Precedence
    String str[]={"MC","MR","MS","M+","M-","<-","CE","C","+/-","sqrt","7","8","9","/","%","4","5","6","*","1/x","1","2","3","-","=","0",".","+"};
    public Calc(String s)
    {
        jf=new JFrame(s);
        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(new Color(213, 219, 255));
        jf.add(p);  
        JMenuBar mb=new JMenuBar();
        jf.setJMenuBar(mb);
        JMenu view=new JMenu("View");
        mb.add(view);
        JMenu edit=new JMenu("Edit");
        mb.add(edit);
        JMenu help=new JMenu("Help");
        mb.add(help);
        JMenuItem viewHelp=new JMenuItem("View Help");
        help.add(viewHelp);
        JMenuItem about=new JMenuItem("About Us");
        help.add(about);
        mb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
        mb.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        mb.setFont(new Font("Time_New_Roaman", 0, 11));
        tf=new JTextField();
        tf2=new JTextField();
        tf.setBackground(new Color(242, 248, 255));
        tf2.setBackground(new Color(242, 248, 255));
        tf2.setBounds(10,10,190,20);
        tf.setBounds(10,29,190,30);
        tf.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(-1, 1, 1, 1),BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(153,153,153))));
        tf2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, -1, 1),BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(153,153,153))));
        tf.setFont(new Font("Time_New_Roaman",0,20));
        tf2.setFont(new Font("Time_New_Roaman",0,14));
        tf.setHorizontalAlignment(tf.RIGHT);
        tf2.setHorizontalAlignment(tf2.RIGHT);
        p.add(tf);
        p.add(tf2);
        tf2.setCaretColor(Color.WHITE);
        for(int i=0,x=10,y=32,h=27,w=34;i<str.length;i++)
        {
            int temp=0;
            if(i==24)
                    h=62;
            if(i==25)
                {
                    w=73;
                    temp=39;
                }
            if(i%5==0)
                {
                    y+=35;
                    x=10;
                }
            if(str[i]=="<-")
            {
                str[i]=""+(char)8592;
            }if(str[i]=="sqrt")
            {
                str[i]="\u221A";
            }if(str[i]=="+/-")
            {
                str[i]="\u00B1";
            }
            b[i]=new JButton(str[i]);
            b[i].setFont(new Font("Arial",0,12));
            if(str[i]=="1/x")
            {b[i].setFont(new Font("Lucida Calligraphy",0, 12)); }
            b[i].setBounds(x,y,w,h);
            b[i].setMargin(new Insets(1,4,1,4));
            if(str[i]==""+(char)8592||str[i]=="=")
            {
                b[i].setFont(new Font("Arial",1,20));
            }
            p.add(b[i]);
            if(str[i]=="1"||str[i]=="2"||str[i]=="3"||str[i]=="4"||str[i]=="5"||str[i]=="6"||str[i]=="7"||str[i]=="8"||str[i]=="9"||str[i]=="0"||str[i]==".")
            {
                b[i].setBackground(new Color(234, 245, 248));
                b[i].setFont(new Font("Arial",0,15));
            }
            b[i].addActionListener(this);
            b[i].addMouseListener(this);
            x+=39+temp;
            h=27;
            w=34;
        }
        p.setLayout(null);
        Toolkit t=jf.getToolkit();
        Dimension screensize=t.getScreenSize();
        int width = screensize.width*8/10;
        int height = screensize.height*8/10;
        jf.setBounds(width/2,height/4,width,height);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setSize(215,330);
        jf.setResizable(false);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
            if(e.getSource()==b[10]||e.getSource()==b[11]||e.getSource()==b[12]||e.getSource()==b[15]||e.getSource()==b[16]||e.getSource()==b[17]||e.getSource()==b[20]||e.getSource()==b[21]||e.getSource()==b[22]||e.getSource()==b[25])
        {hit=1;sqrt=1;pp=1;mp=1;mulp=1;divp=1;remp=1;}
        if(e.getSource()==b[0])             //For MC Button
            {}
        if(e.getSource()==b[1])             //For MR Button
            {}
        if(e.getSource()==b[2])             //For MS Button
            {}
        if(e.getSource()==b[3])             //For M+ Button
            {}
        if(e.getSource()==b[4])             //For M- Button
            {}
        if(e.getSource()==b[5])             //For Backspace Button
            {
                no=1;
                String s=tf.getText();
                tf.setText("");
                for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++)
                {tf.setText(tf.getText()+s.charAt(i));}
                if(s.length()-1==0)
                    tf.setText("0");
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[6])             //For CE Button
            {
                dot=0;no=1;
                tf.setText("0");
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[7])             //For C Button
            {
                tf.setText("0");
                tf2.setText("");
                val1=0;val2=0;hit=0;sqrt=0;plus=1;minus=1;mul=1;div=1;rem=1;dot=0;pp=0;mp=0;mulp=0;divp=0;remp=0;no=1;
                tf.setFont(new Font("Time_New_Roaman",0,20));
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[8])             //For +/- Button
            {}
        if(e.getSource()==b[9])             //For Sqrt Button
            {
                dot=0;no=1;
                tf2.setText("");
                if(sqrt==1)
                {
                    double t;
                    double num=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
                    double squareRoot = num/2;
                    do {
                        t = squareRoot;
                        squareRoot =(t+(num/t))/2;
                        }while((t-squareRoot)!=0);
                    tf2.setText("sqrt("+num+")");
                    tf.setText(""+squareRoot);
                }
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[10])            //For 7 Button
            {
                if(no==1)
                { tf.setText(""); }
                tf.setText(tf.getText().concat("7"));
                no=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[11])            //For 8 Button
            {
                if(no==1)
                {tf.setText("");}
                tf.setText(tf.getText().concat("8"));
                no=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[12])            //For 9 Button
            {if(no==1)
                {tf.setText("");}
                tf.setText(tf.getText().concat("9"));
                no=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[13])            //For / Button
            {
                no=1;dot=0;
                if(div==2 && divp==1)
                {
                    tf2.setText(tf2.getText()+tf.getText()+"/");
                    serve();
                    minus=1;plus=1;mul=1;rem=1;
                }
                if(div==1 && divp==1)
                {
                    div=2;
                    val1=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
                    tf2.setText(tf.getText()+"/");
                    operator=4;
                    tf.setText("");
                }divp=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[14])            //For % Button
            {
                no=1;dot=0;
                if(rem==1 && remp==1)
                {
                    val2=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
                    tf2.setText(tf2.getText()+tf.getText()+"%");
                    result=(val1*val2)/100;
                    tf.setText(""+result);
                    plus=1;mul=1;div=1;minus=1;
                }
                remp=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[15])            //For 4 Button
            {
                if(no==1)
                {tf.setText("");}
                tf.setText(tf.getText().concat("4"));
                no=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[16])            //For 5 Button
            {
                if(no==1)
                {tf.setText("");}
                tf.setText(tf.getText().concat("5"));
                no=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[17])            //For 6 Button
            {
                if(no==1)
                {tf.setText("");}
                tf.setText(tf.getText().concat("6"));
                no=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[18])            //For * Button
            {
                no=1;dot=0;
                if(mul==2 && mulp==1)
                {
                    tf2.setText(tf2.getText()+tf.getText()+"*");
                    serve();
                    minus=1;plus=1;div=1;rem=1;
                }
                if(mul==1 && mulp==1)
                {
                    mul=2;
                    val1=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
                    tf2.setText(tf.getText()+"*");
                    operator=3;
                    tf.setText("");
                }mulp=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[19])            //For 1/x Button
            {}
        if(e.getSource()==b[20])            //For 1 Button
            {
                if(no==1)
                {tf.setText("");}
                tf.setText(tf.getText().concat("1"));
                no=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[21])            //For 2 Button
            {
                if(no==1)
                {tf.setText("");}
                tf.setText(tf.getText().concat("2"));
                no=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[22])            //For 3 Button
            {
                if(no==1)
                tf.setText("");
                tf.setText(tf.getText().concat("3"));
                no=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[23])            //For - Button
            {
                no=1;dot=0;
                if(minus==2 && mp==1)
                {
                    tf2.setText(tf2.getText()+tf.getText()+"-");
                    serve();
                    plus=1;mul=1;div=1;rem=1;
                }
                if(minus==1 && mp==1)
                {
                    minus=2;
                    val1=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
                    tf2.setText(tf.getText()+"-");
                    operator=2;
                    tf.setText("");
                }mp=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[24])            //For = Button
            {
                no=1;dot=0;mp=1;mulp=1;pp=1;divp=1;remp=1;plus=1;minus=1;mul=1;div=1;rem=1;
                if(hit==1)
                {
                    val2=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
                    tf2.setText(tf.getText()+val2);
                switch(operator)
                    {
                        case 1: result=val1+val2;
                                break;
                        case 2: result=val1-val2;
                                break;
                        case 3: result=val1*val2;
                                break;
                        case 4: result=val1/val2;
                                break;
                        default: result=0;
                    }
                tf.setText(""+result);
                tf2.setText("");
                val1=0;
                val2=0;
                }
                else
                {tf.setText(""+result);}
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[25])            //For 0 Button
            { 
                //dot=0;
                if(no==1)
                {tf.setText("");}
                tf.setText(tf.getText().concat("0"));
                no=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[26])            //For dot (.) Button
            {
                if(no==1)
                tf.setText("");
                if(dot==0)
                {
                    dot=1;
                    tf.setText(tf.getText().concat("."));
                }
                if(dot==1)
                {tf.setText(tf.getText());}
                no=0;
            }
        if(e.getSource()==b[27])            //For + Button
            {
                no=1;dot=0;
                if(plus==2 && pp==1)
                {
                    tf2.setText(tf2.getText()+tf.getText()+"+");
                    serve();
                    minus=1;mul=1;div=1;rem=1;
                }
                if(plus==1 && pp==1)
                {
                    plus=2;
                    val1=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
                    tf2.setText(tf.getText()+"+");
                    operator=1;
                    tf.setText("");
                }pp=0;
            }
        if(tf.getText()!="")                // For converting Font When Text is out of range
            {
                int count=0,i;
                String s=tf.getText();
                char ch[]=s.toCharArray();
                //double d=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
                for(i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
                    {
                        //d/=10;
                        count++;
                    }
                if(count>=15&&count<20)
                {
                    tf.setFont(new Font("Time_New_Roaman",1,16));
                }if(count>=20)
                {
                    tf.setFont(new Font("Time_New_Roaman",1,14));
                }
            }
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
        {
            if(me.getSource()==b[i])
                {
                    b[i].setBackground(new Color(255,204,153));
                }
        }
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
        {
            if(me.getSource()==b[i])
                {
                    b[i].setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));
                    if(me.getSource()==b[10]||me.getSource()==b[11]||me.getSource()==b[12]||me.getSource()==b[15]||me.getSource()==b[16]||me.getSource()==b[17]||me.getSource()==b[20]||me.getSource()==b[21]||me.getSource()==b[22]||me.getSource()==b[25]||me.getSource()==b[26])
                    {
                        b[i].setBackground(new Color(234, 245, 248));
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    void serve()
    {
        val2=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
        if(operator==1)
        {
            result=val1+val2;
            pp=0;mp=1;mulp=1;divp=1;remp=1;
        }
        else if(operator==2)
        {
            result=val1-val2;
            mp=0;mulp=1;pp=1;divp=1;remp=1;
        }
        else if(operator==3)
        {
            result=val1*val2;
            mulp=0;pp=1;mp=1;divp=1;remp=1;
        }
        else if(operator==4)
        {
            result=val1/val2;
            mulp=1;pp=1;mp=1;divp=0;remp=1;
        }
        tf.setText("");
        tf.setText(""+result);
        val1=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
    }
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        new Calc("PariGanak");
        Timer time=new Timer();
        time.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run()
        {
            tf.setText("0");
            no=1;
        }
        },100);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.