# How to split a string in Java and then push numbers into one list and operators into another?

Tags: java

I understand splitting a string in Java is something like this:

```
String[] result = userCalcInput.split("[-+*/]");
```

But i want to split say the following expressions.

```
2+2
222*2
2/2+6
120+9/4+22
29*2+9
```

I want the user to be able to enter anything such as the above or their own choice as a string and then i can split this on the operator and push into the different lists. code so far below:

```
    List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> operatorList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner userInputNoOne = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println("Enter your calculation: ");
    userCalcInput = userInputNoOne.next();


    String[] result = userCalcInput.split("[-+*/]");

    if(userCalcInput = int){
        //code here
    }
    else if (userCalcInput = NaN){
        //code here
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

I understand this wont work but just wanted to see if right idea and how to properly implement it.
thanks

Comment: you have asked the similar question few hours back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967226/trying-to-create-a-calculator-in-java

Comment: Young 'Sherlock' Hobbit. :D

Comment: Actually you are both wrong. This question is vastly different. I want to do multiple expressions.@YoungHobbit your answer does not work with more than 1 operator correctly. My attempted solution (if working) would be a lot more powerful. I came here for help and then get shunned by people. ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are quite new to Java.

You could use regular expressions.
Regular expressions allow you to find specific patterns in a string, in that case you want to look for numbers and operators, which are defined separately in a 'regex' : \d for a digit and \W for a non-word character, such as an arithmetic operator.
You should try using the Pattern and Matcher classes